Pyspark efficient ways to iterate over 1M columns
I have a pyspark dataframe as below:
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
|    code|    updatedAt|S0x223433|S1yd33333|S4r256467|
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
|AAAAAAAA|1713292448319|     3243|     null|     3422|
|BBBBBBBB|1689430451041|     3455|     2345|     7654|

I want to add a new column in above dataframe where, for a given row, it will only take those s-prefixed columns that are not null. Result dataframe would look something like below:
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------------------
|    code|    updatedAt|S0x223433|S1yd33333|S4r256467|new_col             |
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------------------
|AAAAAAAA|1713292448319|     3243|     null|     3422|[S0x223433,S4r256467]
|BBBBBBBB|1689430451041|     null|     2345|     7654|[S1yd33333,S4r256467]

My spark dataframe has almost 1M columns and the way I want it to process is like below:

Check if a column name matches a regex

Then check if it has a non-null value, then add it to a list

Return a list of all such columns for a given row


(The list added in new column will be exploded later for normalization purpose)
Current logic to add a new column is taking forever to run (since its a loop running on a 1M columns)
non_null_s_columns= array([when(col(c).isNotNull(), lit(c)) for c in SPrefixedcolumns])
Ask from the community:
Is there an efficient way to perform this? I am relatively new to spark, so might miss an obvious way, if any. I am looking for pointers for glue dynamic frame or spark dataframe where I can do this without iterating over 1M columns. TIA!
I tried dropping null columns but my dataset is sparse, so that wasn't helpful. I am working on writing a UDF to which I can pass a dataframe row and work on populating new column, but no luck so far.

Given:
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
|    code|    updatedAt|S0x223433|S1yd33333|S4r256467|
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
|AAAAAAAA|1713292448319|     3243|     null|     3422|
|BBBBBBBB|1689430451041|     null|     2345|     7654|

Doing:

melt by unique row'd columns and SPrefixedcolumns
dropna to keep the filled column names
groupBy those columns and collect_list the SPrefixedcolumns names
join this back to the original table

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

unique_cols = ["code", "updatedAt"]  # Ensure these make unique rows.
SPrefixedcolumns = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("S")]

df = df.join(
    df.melt(
        ids=unique_cols,
        values=SPrefixedcolumns,
        variableColumnName="variable",
        valueColumnName="value",
    )
    .dropna()
    .groupBy(unique_cols)
    .agg(F.collect_list("variable").alias("new_col")),
    unique_cols,
    "left_outer",
)
df.show()

Output:
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
|    code|    updatedAt|S0x223433|S1yd33333|S4r256467|             new_col|
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
|AAAAAAAA|1713292448319|   3243.0|      NaN|     3422|[S4r256467, S0x22...|
|BBBBBBBB|1689430451041|      NaN|   2345.0|     7654|[S4r256467, S1yd3...|
+--------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+

